# asp.netHow to edit header text in Gridview while joining tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm trying to join 2 tables together. I use linq as my database. My code is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = from c in db.Products
               join o in db.ProductCategories
               on c.ProdC_ID equals o.ProdC_ID
               select new
               {
                   c.Prod_ID,
                   c.Prod_Name,
                   c.Prod_Price,
                   c.Prod_Amount,
                   c.Prod_Picture,
                   c.Prod_Detail,
                   o.ProdC_Name
               };
    GridView1.DataSource = item;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I bound GridView with this code but I can't edit header text for these columns. I try to add new column but it just add a new column in this GridView. Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add desired property name in anonymous class as below

```
var item = from c in db.Products
                   join o in db.ProductCategories
                   on c.ProdC_ID equals o.ProdC_ID
                   select new
                   {
                      ProductID= c.Prod_ID,
                      ProductName =c.Prod_Name,
                      ProductPrice= c.Prod_Price,
                      Amount= c.Prod_Amount,
                       Picture=c.Prod_Picture,
                       ProductDetail=c.Prod_Detail,
                     ProdCName=  o.ProdC_Name
                   };
```